# I can't upload files > 1MB using dropzonejs, ruby-on-rails and puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropzone.js, puma

I am trying to make a web application where people can upload their files, which will be stored on the hard drive then. I am using dropzonejs to handle the file uploads and ruby-on-rails to create my web application.
The problem is that whenever I try to upload a file that is bigger than 1 MB it just hangs on 99.9999% and never gets uploaded fully.

My form is:

```
<%= form_tag '/upload', html: {multipart: true}, class: "dropzone" , id: "media-dropzone" do %>
     <div class="fallback">
        <%= file_field_tag "files", multiple: true%>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

The associated javascript is:

```
<script src="/assets/dropzone.js" type="text/javascript">
    var TOKEN=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dz = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone",{
        url: "/upload_file/upload",
        autoProcessQueue:false,
        uploadMultiple:true,
        addRemoveLinks:true,
        maxFiles:2,
        parallelUploads:2,
        acceptedFiles: text/xml,
        params:{
            'authenticity_token': TOKEN
        }        });

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        if(dz.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dz.processQueue();
        }
    });
</script>
```

My rails server runs puma 3.9.1

**EDIT**

[A picture of the hanging upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGgQc.png)

Comment: Do you have fron-end webserver like `nginx` ? If yes, check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: No I don't have a front-end web server yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pavel, I remembered to install nginx, and this fixed my problem